# How do I restart steam?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

Lately I have been having issues going into Team Fortress 2. It will show that team fortress 2 is preparing to launch and then close. I heard from a certain useless member that restarting steam might help. However, said member failed to mention how to do so. So I looked around on the internet to find out how to restart steam. All attempts have been a fail. Some sources were trolls, viruses (no I did not fall for those), outdated, or involved me going into files and or taking many hours to do so. How do I restart steam in a quick and easy way that does not involve me digging through many files? I am not exactly good with computers and I am still figuring mine out. So please keep it simple.

Answer (score 5):

Restarting Steam simply refers to closing Steam and opening it again. To do this, click on 'Steam' in the top right corner then click 'Exit'.
[image]
Once Steam has closed, start it again by clicking on Steam in the start menu or double clicking the desktop icon.

Comment: you have 7 unread messages btw :D

Comment: @Jenson I'm pretty sure they are 7 new trading cards. I'll try to contain my excitement.

Comment: On Windows, you can also do this by right-clicking the Steam Icon on your toolbar (shows up next to your computer clock) and selecting "exit" directly from there.

Comment: As I recall, if this is Windows, this answer is outright wrong... Steam will continue running in the system tray until you do what @Jenson said in the comments on the question itself (and what Zibbobz just said).  I'm not at a computer with Steam installed to check it, though.

Comment: @Powerlord That's true for X'ing out the window, but not for Steam > Exit. I just tested it on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Click Steam in the upper right and select 'Change user'. You can then proceed to log in using the same credentials. This effectively restarts steam exactly as if you exited the program and re-launched it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your Task Manager by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete and clicking on that. You then go "Processes" and find **Steam.exe *32**. Click it and "End the Process." **Do not click the steamwebhelper *32**. These two processes are different. After that, you can login to your Steam account again.

Comment: He said he's not that savvy with computers ... opening a task-manager is most likely too much for him.^^

Comment: Pro tip: Control-shift-escape skips the dumb windows screen and pops open Task Manager directly.

Comment: ok so problem. I could not find steam.exe *32

Answer (score 0):

Here let me show you click Steam in the upper right and select `Change user`. You can then proceed to log in using the same account credentials. This effectively restarts steam exactly as if you exited the program and re-launched it. If you wanna do it advanced You can open your Task Manager by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> and clicking on that